# How can I calculate the value `f(x)` in this table?

Tags: functions, list-manipulation

I am trying to find `f(0)` and `f(3)` to list them into a table, but I can not get that values. That is mean, I want to list the points `(0, 0)` and `(3, -(9/2))` into table. I can not the correct result. My code

```
list = {x^2 - 3 x};
Clear[pA];
list1 = Table[pA = points;
   Integrate[pA, x], {points, list}];
Table[f[x_] := extra;
 {f[x], sol = Solve[D[f[x], x] == 0, x, Reals]; x1 = x /. sol[[1]];
  x2 = x /. sol[[2]]; {x1, f[x1]}, {x2, f[x2]}}, {extra, list1}]
```

I only get

> {{-((3 x^2)/2) + x^3/
>      3, {0, -((3 x^2)/2) + x^3/3}, {3, -((3 x^2)/2) + x^3/3}}}

How can I get the correct result?

Comment: No. It is a  function or a list of functions.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Please try with `list = {x^2 - 3 x, x^3 + 5 x};`

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I saw my bug in syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using `SetDelayed` and suppressing the output with `;` on every iteration of `Table` is probably not the best way to handle evaluating this particular loop.

You could try:

```
list = {x^2 - 3 x};
Clear[pA]
list1 = Table[Integrate[points, x], {points, list}];
Table[{x, extra} /. Solve[D[extra, x]==0, x, Reals], {extra, list1}]
```

or, more succinctly:

```
list = {x^2 - 3 x};
list1 = Integrate[#, x]&/@list;
{x, #} /. Solve[D[#, x] == 0, x, Reals]&/@list1
```

The output of either is `{{{0, 0}, {3, -9/2}}}`. With your updated example in the comments, the output becomes `{{{0, 0}, {3, -(9/2)}}, {{0, 0}}}` meaning that `output[[1]]` is the set of solutions to the first equation, and `output[[2]]` is the set of solutions to the second equation (of course there appears to only be one solution for the second equation, but it's still represented as `{{0, 0}}`).

Comment: How can I input the function extra into the table?

Comment: I did `Table[{extra, {x, extra} /. 
   Solve[D[extra, x] == 0, x, Reals]}, {extra, list1}]`

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Ah, sorry, I didn’t see that part of the question. But, yes, that should be an effective way to include the function itself.

Comment: How can I calculate are of the triangle OAB, where O(0,0), A and B are extra points of the graph of the function?